# Terraform remote-exec creating forever

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a terraform `main.tf` and which has a `remote-exec` provisioner to create a file, but it takes forever and gives the following error

> Error: timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (root@34.94.107.128:22): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none], no supported methods remain

And it never stops.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
resource "null_resource" "web3" {
  triggers = {
    key = "${uuid()}"
  }
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "touch /etc/machan_kohomada_remote_execution"
    ]
    connection {
        type = "ssh"
        host = google_compute_instance.first-two-servers[0].network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
    }
  }
}
```

I think maybe I am using the `remote-exec` function in a wrong way? What I need to do is:

**I need to create a file `/etc/remote_execution` in each google compute server**

Comment: Can you login to `34.94.107.128` as `root` user with ssh key?

Comment: Usually instances in cloud have some sort of `cloud-user` who can `sudo` to root. Direct root login will be disabled.

Comment: @harshavmb i am using gcloud commands to login into the server. what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you try to login manually without gcloud commands?

Comment: Yes. Using the ssh <public-ip>, I can `ssh`

Comment: The key item is what user? On GCP images, the root user is disabled for SSH login unless you changed the configuration.